# Why am I not able to vertically center my row in either a tabular or tikz matrix environment?

Tags: tables, tikz-matrix

Neither of these two MWE center the content of the rows.  Why?

Example 1 using a `tabular` environment`

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\def\aecaseA{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y}
      \\= 
      2x-2y
      \end{gather*}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\aecaseB{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y} 
      \\= 
      2x
    \end{gather*}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\aecaseC{%%
   No such points.
  }

\def\aecaseD{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y} 
      \\= 
      0
    \end{gather*}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
   \fbox{Case $x\geq y$} & {$y\geq 0$} & {$y<0$}    \\
   {$x\geq 0$}           & {\aecaseA}  & {\aecaseB} \\
   {$x<0$}               & {\aecaseC}  & {\aecaseD} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Example 2 using a `TikZ` `matrix`

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\def\aecaseA{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y}
      \\= 
      2x-2y
      \end{gather*}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\aecaseB{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y} 
      \\= 
      2x
    \end{gather*}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\aecaseC{%%
   No such points.
  }

\def\aecaseD{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y} 
      \\= 
      0
    \end{gather*}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={align=center,inner sep=0pt,anchor=center}]
  {
   \fbox{Case $x\geq y$} & {$y\geq 0$} & {$y<0$}    \\
   {$x\geq 0$}           & {\aecaseA}  & {\aecaseB} \\
   {$x<0$}               & {\aecaseC}  & {\aecaseD} \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default vertical alignment of `minipage` is `c` so it is centred, for some definition of centre.

Adding a rule may make it clearer:

```
   {$x<0$}               & {\aecaseC}
```

[image]

I guess you want to kill the space above the alignment. I have a feeling one of the `mathtools` extensions may help there, I may look later....

---

`\showbox` confirms you have spurious `\abovedisplayskip` so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\def\aecaseA{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y}
      \\= 
      2x-2y
      \end{gather*}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\aecaseB{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y} 
      \\= 
      2x
    \end{gather*}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\aecaseC{%%
   No such points.
  }

\def\aecaseD{%%
  \begin{minipage}{2in}\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
    \begin{gather*}
      \abs{x-y}+\abs{x}-\abs{y} 
      \\= 
      0
    \end{gather*}
\end{minipage}}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ccc}
   \fbox{Case $x\geq y$} & {$y\geq 0$} & {$y<0$}    \\
   {$x\geq 0$}           & {\aecaseA}  & {\aecaseB} \\
   {$x<0$}               & {\aecaseC}  & aaa\vrule{\aecaseD} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```